# Google Gson preserve generic signatures

Tags: generics, gson, proguard, android-r8

Crashes in Firebase Crashlytics appear with a note how to fix a problem:

*Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: TypeToken must be created with a type argument: new TypeToken<...>() {}; When using code shrinkers (ProGuard, R8, ...) make sure that generic signatures are preserved.*

My generic class between angle brackets <...> is named **ApiResponse**. I created it with **jsonschema2pojo**.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

An exclusion for serialized/deserialized classes over Gson is needed. For a package containing your classes looks like this

```
# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.myapplication.model.api.** { *; }
```

Also add this

```
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with
# fields. Proguard removes such information by default, keep it.
-keepattributes Signature

# This is also needed for R8 in compat mode since multiple 
# optimizations will remove the generic signature such as class 
# merging and argument removal. See: 
# https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/main/compatibility-faq.md#troubleshooting-gson-gson
-keep class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken { *; }
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

# Optional. For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes AnnotationDefault,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
```

Comment: Are you sure this addressed the issue? Please also take a look at https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/main/compatibility-faq.md#troubleshooting-gson-gson, where the `TypeToken` handling is explained.

Comment: Also consider using `-keepattributes AnnotationDefault,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations` instead of `-keepattributes *Annotation*`.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your constribution. I corrected the post.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/google/gson/pull/2397 for consumer rules being added to GSON.

Comment: Full proguard file: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/gson/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/gson.pro